# Angular compareFn set only Id field

Tags: angular

I have a question. Why when I try set value to Form control with compareWith function - in my valueChanges and value is only id field (without name and other prop) but in template all dispays correctly.

this is example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-angular-a9wowt?file=app/app.component.ts

```
setting {id: 2} - i get in value {id: 2} instead of { id: 2, name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA' }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you set explicitly `setValue({ id: 2 });`. So at init you see only this. Do the follow as example:     `this.selectedCountriesControl.setValue(this.states[1]);`. Thats all.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedCountriesControl.setValue(this.states[1]);
  }
```

But for what is it then good?

> We set the default option by passing the object reference through the FormControl constructor. Problem is now that when we repopulate our options list(for example through an HTTP call), the object reference is gone and the model binding of our selected value is lost.

Read all about [here](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2017/12/angularcomparewith.html).